# Please explain this BASH command "cat /y//.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

Tags: bash

What does this command mean?

```
cat /y//.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I know that cat is a concatenate command and `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is probably the target file `id_rsa.pub` in directory `.ssh`

But what is the `/y//` all about?

I don't know bash, well out of my comfort zone and when I try to display help, it doesn't help (me):

```
$ cat --help
Usage: cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -A, --show-all           equivalent to -vET
  -b, --number-nonblank    number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
  -e                       equivalent to -vE
  -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line
  -n, --number             number all output lines
  -s, --squeeze-blank      suppress repeated empty output lines
  -t                       equivalent to -vT
  -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
  -u                       (ignored)
  -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Examples:
  cat f - g  Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
  cat        Copy standard input to standard output.

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Report any translation bugs to <https://translationproject.org/team/>
Full documentation <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cat>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) cat invocation'
```

Comment: `/y//.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is just a file path. An odd-looking file path, but `cat` isn't going to do anything special, it's just going to look for that file.

Comment: It may be some nasty path that poor `cygwin` has to use on Windows.

Comment: On Windows, the `//` would separate a drive specifier from the path on that drive, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now that you say this, I think it is a path to my mapped Y drive.  I saw this typed when someone was generating my private and public keys for Git and I wanted to understand what was being done. I guess he was just checking to see if the files were created, eh?

Comment: @Ivan It sounds like he was getting the public key to copy to the remote.

Comment: Related: [How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/117037)